# How can I modify the contents of an image with a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, images, image-manipulation

Say I want to overwrite the top half of a file "image.png" with white pixels. Can I do that with a bash script?

Comment: Please have a *specific* question. Ask how to do something, don't ask `is X possible?`, because you're surely not looking for a 'yes/no' answer. Spoiler: yes it is.

Comment: [https://imagemagick.org/index.php](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Comment: Please note that bash is just a shell, and not an editor. I assume you're looking for any sort of command-line solution?  What Operating System environment is this in?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `netpbm` tools; it should be installable through your package manager.

```
pngtopnm image.png > image.pnm
halfheight=$(awk 'NR==2 { printf "%d", $2/2 }' image.pnm)
pnmcut -top "$halfheight" image.pnm | pnmpad -white -top "$halfheight" | pnmtopng > out.png
rm image.pnm
```

1. Convert the PNG image to the PNM format
2. The image dimensions are stored in the second line of the PNM image. Print half of the height (second field $2 / 2) as integer using `awk` and save the value in variable `halfheight`.
3. Cut off half of the height from the top, pad the result with the same amount of pixels with a top white border and convert the output back to the PNG format.
4. Clean up the temporary file.

If you want to calculate the height in a more "bashy" way, you could save the image dimensions in an array and then calculate the value:

```
dim=($(head -n2 image.pnm | tail -n1))
halfheight=$((${dim[1]} / 2))
```

Links:

- [Netpbm documentation](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/)
- [Netpbm Program Directory](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/directory.html) (list of all programs)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using imagemagick's draw command:

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw

Example:

```
w=$(identify -format %w input.png)
h=$(identify -format %h input.png)
convert -draw "rectangle 0,0 ${w},$((h/2))" -fill white input.png output.png
```

Comment: Can you [give an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/724395/edit) of how this would be used?

Answer (score 0):

Create a starting image with top half readily distinguishable from bottom:

```
magick -size 640x480 gradient:red-blue image.png
```

[image]

**Newer ImageMagick versions**

```
magick image.png -region "x50%" -fill white -colorize 100% result.png
```

Or

```
magick image.png -region "640x%[fx:h/2]" -fill white -colorize 100% result.png
```

Same result as below.

**Older ImageMagick versions**

Now, do the following:

- split into 2 halves, i.e. top and bottom
- discard the top, retain the bottom
- clone the bottom and fill 100% with white
- put the white half before the bottom half
- append original bottom half below white

---

```
magick image.png -crop x2@ -delete 0 \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100% \) +swap -append result.png
```

I artificially added a black border so you can see the extent on this white background.

[image]